# Payroll System architecture deisgn

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, system

I have to design a Payroll solution for scratch targetting US region (but will have plan to add support for other regions as well). Please suggest overall System architecture for payroll solutions.
I am more interested to discuss on System Design Patterns and different components, instead of coding language.

e.g. for Enterprise integrations, we have https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/). It eliminates most of the complexity in building reliable business processes.